# Cannot login to huawei E5172 via SSH

Tags: router, ssh

I have huawei  E5172 router.When I try to login via ssh ,I get this

```
ssh -v admin@192.168.1.1


OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.1 [192.168.1.1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version dropbear_0.50
debug1: no match: dropbear_0.50
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client 3des-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server 3des-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 3e:75:5f:41:69:d1:67:42:5e:d1:03:db:c8:04:90:84
debug1: Host '192.168.1.1' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:6
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
admin@192.168.1.1's password: 
debug1: Authentications that can continue: password
```

I have not set up any SSH password and the configuration on the web page doesn’t give any option for setting a password.I tried to use admin as a password thought that might be the default password and it returned

```
Permission denied, please try again.
```

Comment: For this router the default username and password are both "admin"

Comment: when I use the word "admin" as a password to login to ssh , it returns Permission denied, please try again.

Comment: Have you tried logging in through the web GUI with a browser? That will confirm whether the issue is with SSH or the password. You could also try resetting the router.

Comment: I can login to the web GUI without any issue

Comment: With username and password both "admin"?

Comment: There is an article here https://blog.hqcodeshop.fi/archives/151-Huawei-B593-Logging-into-shell-Solved!.html for a different Huawei model that suggest the Web and Shell passwords are different ...

Comment: yes , in the web GUI the user and password are both admin

Comment: From the [user manual](http://setuprouter.com/router/huawei/e5172s-920/manual-1260.pdf) - "The CPE 
supports SSH diagnostics. If this function is required, contact Huawei via mobile@huawei.com"